# Can I count two different things on the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table like this:

```
// question_and_answers
+----+---------+---------------+--------+------+
| id |  title  |      body     | amount | type |
+----+---------+---------------+--------+------+
| 1  | t1      | b1            | NULL   | 0    |
| 2  | t2      | b2            | NULL   | 1    |
| 3  | t3      | b3            | NULL   | 1    |
| 4  | t4      | b4            | 100    | 0    |
| 5  | t5      | b5            | NULL   | 0    |
| 6  | t6      | b6            | NULL   | 1    |
| 7  | t7      | b7            | 50     | 0    |
+----+---------+---------------+--------+------+
```

And I have two queries:

## 1: the number of questions:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM question_and_answers WHERE type = 0
```

## 2: the number of paid questions:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM question_and_answers WHERE type = 0 AND amount IS NOT NULL
```

---

Can I combine those two queries? I mean can I write one query instead of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT sum(type = 0 AND amount IS NOT NULL),
       count(*) 
FROM question_and_answers 
WHERE type = 0
```

In MySQL the result of a comparision is `0` or `1`. You can sum those results up like in the above query.

To make it work for other DB engines you could use this general ANSI SQL approach:

```
SELECT sum(case when type = 0 AND amount IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end),
       count(*)
FROM question_and_answers 
WHERE type = 0
```

or with `count()`:

```
SELECT count(case when type = 0 AND amount IS NOT NULL then 1 else null end),
       count(*) 
FROM question_and_answers 
WHERE type = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote. Just why `sum()`? Why not `count()`? since I just want to count the number of rows, not aggregating something.

Comment: I would add the condition `where type = 0`. It won't change the result, but can improve the performance.

Comment: You can use count() as well but count does count all non-null values no matter what they are. So you would have to use something like `sum(case when type = 0 then 1 else null end)`

Comment: yes .. adding a condition like `where type = 0` would make it more fast. Since I've an index on `type` column

Comment: Honestly I don't understand .. You have this condition `type=0` on the `where` clause. So why do you need it on aggregation function again? In other word, is there any different between your first query and [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28e822a092969f4ef77446c3c6494438)?

Comment: @MartinAJ with the WHERE condition you can replace `sum(type=0)` with `count(*)`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel and replace `sum(type = 0 AND amount IS NOT NULL)` with `sum(amount IS NOT NULL)`, right?

Comment: Even better: `select count(amount), count(*)` :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yeah .. great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use blow query:

```
select count(1) as count1  , sum(if(amount is not null,1,0)) as count2 from question_and_answers where type=0
```

**count1** for count of (type=0) ,
**count2** for count of (type=0 and amount is not null) . 
If you use sql server , use IIF instead of IF in query.